# please explain how padding works?if i increase the padding ,it become smaller and if i decrease the padding,it become larger?but why?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```dart
        body:SafeArea(
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
            child: FlatButton(
              textColor: Colors.white,
              color: Colors.green,
              child: Text(
                'True',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                ),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                //The user picked true.
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
        );
```

Comment: the `Padding` official docs say: *"A widget that insets its child by the given padding.

When passing layout constraints to its child, padding shrinks the constraints by the given padding, causing the child to layout at a smaller size. Padding then sizes itself to its child's size, inflated by the padding, effectively creating empty space around the child."* - whats unclear in that?

Comment: padding: EdgeInsets.all(40.0) mean the box will be bigger,right?
there will 40px padding around the Text(Text is true),
but the box becomes smaller

Comment: What do you mean by "it becomes smaller"? What becomes smaller?

Answer (score 3):

`padding` is the space between the content and the border. If what you need is the space between the widget border and its surrounding, you need the margin property. `margin` is the space outside the border.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for margin :

- margin : Empty space to **surround** the child
- padding : Empty space
  to **inscribe inside** the child

I mix up these two all the time.